# Any suggestion on how to improve tesseract accursity in my app?

Tags: ocr, opencl, tesseract, text-processing

I am working on the project to parse the data from screenshots. I am using python, OpenCV, and PyTesseract.

What I do with the image before sending it to tesseract:

1. Crop an image, so only required text will be parsed
2. Replace all red colors with white (for some reason tesseract can't detect red text)
3. Make image black/white
4. Scale it 1.5x

[Code example here](https://pastebin.com/jDBNasbZ)

In 95% of the cases, it works fine, but I still get some bugs where `'8' parsed as 'B'`, `'5' as 'S'/'$'`, etc.

Examples of: [input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muKZI.jpg) and how the image looks [after OpenCV processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlY50.jpg)

​

Can you give me any suggestions on how detection can be improved in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to [read docs](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/ImproveQuality.md) and you try to interpret your experience ('for some reason tesseract can't detect red text') - it is always tricky ;-)

With tesseract version 5 and eng data model best I got this result:

```
> tesseract inverted.png - --dpi 96

Accessory Life Stone - Level 76
price: 400 000, count: 6
Accessory Life Stone - Level 80
price: 880 000, count: 12
Accessory Life Stone - Level 82
price: 1 000 000, count: 2

Adamantine
price: 18 300, count: 50

Adamantite Earring
price: 1 000 000

Adamantite Necklace
price: 1200 000

Adamantite Necklace Chain
price; 18 000, count: 6

Adamantite Nugget
price: 23 000, count: 1
Adamantite Ring
price: 675 000
```